# Navigation View - Support Google

Tags: android, sql-update, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I am doing an application where I want to put the user name in nav_header_home.xml (top) but I am not able to send the name parameter obtained at the moment the user logs in to the activity home. I am using to send:

```
abreInicio.putExtra("nome_usuario", dados[3]);
```

and to receive, in the java da home I have:

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
String nomeusuario, email;
TextView txtpontosr, txtnome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

txtnome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtnome);
txtpontosr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpontosr);

nomeusuario = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nome_usuario");
email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email_usuario");
```

Also I would like to put the user's points in the same place, this is not fixed, so how can I implement a swipe refresh in activity home to update this data?

Finally I would like advice, for a better UI would be better a navigation view with activities and in those activities in the tolbar a back or a navigation view with activities that have navigation view or fragments?

Answer (score 0):

In your intent, your are passing an array of String. Instead, make your String an ArrayList and accept it in your activity